# Change parameter name FORM_WITH VS FORM_FOR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, form-for

I am using rails 5 and the `form_with` helper. My code works when using `Form_for`, but not `Form_with`.  Is the `:as` parameter not valid with `Form_with`?

## View

```
<%= form_with(model: @user_wizard , :as => :user_wizard, url: validate_step_wizard_path, local: true, builder: BsFormBuilder) do |f| %>
```

## Model

```
def user_wizard_params
   params.require(:user_wizard).permit( :name )
 end
```

However, every time I try to submit the form, the parameter submits:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"LvRDsdfsdfsd3V0l4NLg14q2JWBdwkDPqUIu2l7SXDiioCtvMwW6Bv3ss/LPSS9+bdxiPIzjg==",
 "current_step"=>"step1",
 "wizard_user_step1"=>
  {"name"=>"Name"}
}
```

I have been following this.. https://medium.com/@nicolasblanco/developing-a-wizard-or-multi-steps-forms-in-rails-d2f3b7c692ce

However, my code I use Form_with and they use Form_for. I don't know what the difference is.

Answer (score 2):

Rails `form_with` replaced the `as` option with `scope`, which has the same functionality. Your example should look like this:

```
<%= form_with(model: @wizard , scope: :user_wizard) do |f| %>
```

Now your inputs should have names like `user_wizard[attribute]`.

Answer (score -1):

**form_for** using underlying model instance for example here @post as a model

```
<%= form_for @post do |form| %>
 <%= form.text_field :author %>
 <%= form.submit “Create” %>
<% end %>
```

**form_tag** is form helper but `don't have` underlying model and you should use text_field_tag instead of text_field

```
<%= form_tag “/posts” do %>
 <%= text_field_tag “post[author]” %>
 <%= submit_tag “Create” %>
<% end %>
```

**form_with** will combine form_for and form_tag and later these two will be unify with form_with

here implementation of form_for and form_tag using form_with, as you can see below the difference, 
if you passing form_with with a model it will work as form_for but if you passing it url then it will work as form_tag

```
<%= form_with model: @post do |form| %>
 <%= form.text_field :author %>
 <%= form.submit “Create” %>
<% end %>

<%= form_with url: “/posts” do |form| %>
 <%= form.text_field :author %>
 <%= form.submit “Create” %>
<% end %>
```

meanwhile for your problem there is no options `as`, you can check from this link for [more detail options](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with)

Comment: Why would they get rid of the "as"? It seems very useful? Is Form_for going to be depreciated?